# Device to device communication in Windows 10 IoT Core

Tags: windows-10, iot

What technologies are recommended when we want to do Device-to-device communication in an IoT Scenario? Does Windows 10 IoT Core have support for this type of communication? Could I use AMQP connections for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Device to device communication can happen on multiple levels. Setting up an AMQP server might be feasible using implementations like Apache QPid but this doesn't seem like a responsibility device should be bothered with.  You could run an API server on a W10 IoT Core device for other devices to communicate with.

There are specific standards like [AllJoyn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AllJoyn) that lets us communicate device with eachother and Windows IoT Core has native support for this. Take at look at the samples to find out if this fits your scenario: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/win10/samples/alljoynjs